# Post multipart imagens using Fast Android Networking

Tags: image, android-studio, post, kotlin, multiparameter

I'm using Fast Android Networking library in my project.

My goal is to make a post with multiple parameters, like the image above.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MD9lW.png)

What I'm trying to acomplish is to send a file with image from my app to a webservice.

Here is my code:

**Kotlin:**

```
fun postFotosFeridas() {
    AndroidNetworking.post("http://192.168.254.80/F3M.MpDS.API/api/F3MMpDSImages/")
            .addHeaders("Authorization", Token_Type + " " + New_Token)
            .addHeaders("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
            .addBodyParameter("NomeDaFoto", FotoName)
            .addBodyParameter(FileBody(File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString()
                    + File.separator
                    + "Today"
                    + File.separator
                    + "Today_20181116155706.jpg")))
            .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
            .build()
            .getAsOkHttpResponse(object : OkHttpResponseListener {
                override fun onResponse(response: Response?) {
                    if (response != null) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful) {

                            toast(response.toString())
                        }
                        toast(response.toString())
                    }
                    toast(response.toString())

                }
                override fun onError(anError: ANError?) {
                    toast(anError.toString())
                }

            })
}
```

Comment: did u have solution ??? i have same issue the api type is post